# Puppeteer Waiting for target frame Ubuntu digitalocean

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, timeout, puppeteer, chromium

I have been building a webscraper in Node.js and running it on a digital ocean Ubuntu server. Puppeteer is only having issues on Ubuntu for my program.

I originally had an issue running Puppeteer with root user so I switched to a new account I made on the server and now I have this new issue.

Version: HeadlessChrome/105.0.5173.0

> Error: Waiting for target frame D0E4A57B880331E15F232D467A28499A
> failed
> at Timeout._onTimeout (/home/pricepal/priceServer-deployment/price-server/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/cjs/puppeteer/common/util.js:447:18)
> at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:564:17)
> at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:507:7)

Node.js v18.7.0

Here is the block of code that the program stops at and eventually errors out:

```
try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
        const page = await browser.newPage()
        await page.goto(link)
        const content = await page.content()
        await browser.close()
        return content
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
```

It takes a little longer than normal to generate the headless browser but the error is stemming from a timeout happening at page.goto(link). All of the links fail to load not just one in particular.

The links I am using work when ran on my m1 mac with the same chromium and node versions.

I have been doing research and trying new things all day but I cannot get it fixed and have found little resourced relating to this issue.

Comment: try puppeteer v15

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, been pulling my hair out looking for answers the past few days. I know it's not exactly a proper answer (mods sorry if you have to delete this), but I found that switching from Ubuntu to Debian `10` magically fixed everything. FWIW the line causing the error is:

```
const page = await browser.newPage()
```

I suspect the issue lies somewhere within the version of Chromium that Puppeteer downloads, and its interaction with the OS. What exactly though I couldn't say. My results are as follows:

**Didn't work:**

- Ubuntu `22.04`
- Ubuntu `20.04`
- Debian `11`

**Worked:**

- Debian `10`

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Also, I got it to work for a single webpage at a time, I think the 1 vCPU core and  1Gb memory Ubuntu server just weren't enough resources compared to what I have on the mac mini that I developed (and tested) the program on.